# Retrofit 1.9 how to get http response status from Synchronous Requests

Tags: android, multithreading, retrofit

I have some inherited code and its doing a Synchronous webservice Requests using retrofit.  Its' actually all off the main thread but the call itself is synchronous on that child thread.  Basically what i have inherited is someone has created a child thread and then done the following call:

```
TaskService taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(TaskService.class);  
List<Task> tasks = taskService.getTasks();
```

Where createService is a retrofit call to get a bunch of tasks returned.  Keep in mind this is retrofit 1.9 , how can i get the http response from this ? i need to know if it passed or failed by the http response code ? My end goal is to have analytics based on response code, throughout my network calls.

Comment: You could use an interceptor for handling scenarios. https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors

Comment: Did you try using interceptors.

Comment: yes interceptors would work but the way my project is structured i have this in another injected class called a SessionAdministrator.java.  In this class i set up a global interceptor for all calls. i dont want to track analytics from there as it takes away from single responsibility.

Comment: You can set interceptor for a service by using a different instance of http client with retrofit. That way you can track it at that level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing i could do is assume 200 if everything is ok and then in a try catch capture retrofitError and then get the status code from it.

```
 try{
TaskService taskService = ServiceGenerator.createService(TaskService.class);  
List<Task> tasks = taskService.getTasks(); 
 //got a response, assume 200 ok...
}

catch (RetrofitError error){
Log.d(error.getBody().getStatus() + "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can active logging of Retrofit by this way:

```
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()  
    .setEndpoint(API_LOCATION)
    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) 
    .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));
```

Read more about logging in Retrofit 1.9 from [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-using-the-log-level-to-debug-requests) and Retrofit 2 [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-log-requests-and-responses)

Comment: no, i need the http response in code , i am using it as an analytic.  I need it stored in a variable.